# Unable to use some of the c++ features of OpenCV in Android

Tags: android, c++, opencv, android-ndk

I am developing an Android application that involves some image processing. I am using Open CV. I integrated the open CV adding new module for Java and integrated for the native c++ as well. I can use the library in Java with no issues. But in C++, I am having some issues. Please see the code below.

```
//
// Created by iljim on 03/04/2018.
//
#include <jni.h>
#include <string>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
extern "C"
JNIEXPORT jstring



JNICALL
Java_media_memento_memento_VRPhotoSphereActivity_convertEquiRectToCubeMap(
        JNIEnv *env,
        jobject /* this */, jlong addrMat, jlong addrNewMat) {


    Mat& in = *(Mat*)addrMat;
    Mat& face = *(Mat*)addrNewMat;

    float faceTransform[6][2] =
            {
                    {0, 0},
                    {M_PI / 2, 0},
                    {M_PI, 0},
                    {-M_PI / 2, 0},
                    {0, -M_PI / 2},
                    {0, M_PI / 2}
            };



    int faceId = 0;
    int width = -1;
    int height = -1;

    float inWidth = in.cols;
    float inHeight = in.rows;

    // Allocate map
    Mat mapx(height, width, CV_32F); //Please pay attention to this line.


}
```

In the above code, pay attention to the the line, "Mat mapx(height, width, CV_32F);". When I am writing code, I got no error. I can use Mat of OpenCV c++ library and import the required libraries as well. As you can see below. No error.
[image]

The problem is when I run my app, it is giving me compilation error in the logcat because of the line I highlighted.

This is the error.

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
C:\Users\iljim\Desktop\OpenCV-3.1.0-android-sdk\OpenCV-android-sdk\sdk\native\jni\include\opencv2\core\mat.inl.hpp
Error:(571) undefined reference to 'cv::fastFree(void*)'
Error:(663) undefined reference to 'cv::Mat::create(int, int const*, int)'
Error:(682) undefined reference to 'cv::Mat::deallocate()'
Error:error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
C:\Users\iljim\Desktop\memento\memento-android\app\src\main\cpp\cubemap.cpp
Warning:(280, 1) warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
Warning:(280, 1) warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
```

This is the screenshot

[image]

I believe I integrated the OpenCV for c++ correctly that is why it is not giving me any error when I was typing in some code that using features of OpenCV and was able to import the OpenCV libraries.

This is my CMakeList file

```
# Sets the minimum version of CMake required to build your native library.
# This ensures that a certain set of CMake features is available to
# your build.

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)


include_directories(C:/Users/iljim/Desktop/OpenCV-3.1.0-android-sdk/OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/include)
add_library( lib_opencv SHARED IMPORTED )
set_target_properties(lib_opencv PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/jniLibs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libopencv_java3.so)




# Specifies a library name, specifies whether the library is STATIC or
# SHARED, and provides relative paths to the source code. You can
# define multiple libraries by adding multiple add_library() commands,
# and CMake builds them for you. When you build your app, Gradle
# automatically packages shared libraries with your APK.

add_library( # Specifies the name of the library.
             native-lib

             # Sets the library as a shared library.
             SHARED

             # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
             src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp )

add_library( # Specifies the name of the library.
            cubemap

             # Sets the library as a shared library.
             SHARED

             # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
             src/main/cpp/cubemap.cpp )




# Searches for a specified prebuilt library and stores the path as a
# variable. Because system libraries are included in the search path by
# default, you only need to specify the name of the public NDK library
# you want to add. CMake verifies that the library exists before
# completing its build.

find_library( # Sets the name of the path variable.
              log-lib

              # Specifies the name of the NDK library that
              # you want CMake to locate.
              log )

# Specifies libraries CMake should link to your target library. You
# can link multiple libraries, such as libraries you define in the
# build script, prebuilt third-party libraries, or system libraries.

target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
                       native-lib

                       # OpenCV lib
                       lib_opencv

                       # Cubemap lib
                       cubemap

                       # Links the target library to the log library
                       # included in the NDK.
                       ${log-lib} )
```

What is wrong with my code? What might be the possible error? How can I fix it?